# trying to determine the difference between two groups, what statistical test should I use? They are not independent from each other

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, inference

I am trying to determine which group (A or B) would be better suited for my final analysis. Group a was derived from certain occupations in a specific industry while group B was derived from different types of industries (including the specific industry in group A).

I am just trying to figure out how big of a difference this will make on my outcome if I used 1 group versus the other and therefore need to test this.

Since observations are not independent and not normal, I would assume that the mann whitney u and t test are not plausible.

Suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Edit: outcome is numeric and continuous